# bq cli tool unable to connect to server

Tags: google-bigquery, gcloud

I'm trying to use the bq tool in my docker container, but I am having difficulty connecting.  I have ran `gcloud init`, also, I can query on webui and outside of docker container w/ `bq`.

```
bq query --format=prettyjson --nouse_legacy_sql 'select count(*) from `bigquery-public-data.samples.shakespeare`'
```

> BigQuery error in query operation: Cannot contact server. Please try
>   again. Traceback: Traceback (most recent call last): File
>   "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/bq/bigquery_client.py", line 886,
>   in BuildApiClient response_metadata, discovery_document =
>   http.request(discovery_url) File
>   "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/bq/third_party/oauth2client_4_0/transport.py",
>   line 176, in new_request redirections, connection_type) File
>   "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/bq/third_party/oauth2client_4_0/transport.py",
>   line 283, in request connection_type=connection_type) File
>   "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/bq/third_party/httplib2/**init**.py",
>   line 1626, in request (response, content) = self._request(conn,
>   authority, uri, request_uri, method, body, headers, redirections,
>   cachekey) File
>   "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/bq/third_party/httplib2/**init**.py",
>   line 1368, in _request (response, content) = self._conn_request(conn,
>   request_uri, method, body, headers) File
>   "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/bq/third_party/httplib2/**init**.py",
>   line 1288, in _conn_request conn.connect() File
>   "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/bq/third_party/httplib2/**init**.py",
>   line 1082, in connect raise SSLHandshakeError(e) SSLHandshakeError:
>   [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed
>   (_ssl.c:726)

```
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="9"
VERSION="9 (stretch)"
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
```

The pip freeze is

```
airflow==1.8.0
alembic==0.8.10
asn1crypto==0.24.0
BigQuery-Python==1.14.0
boto==2.49.0
cachetools==2.1.0
certifi==2018.10.15
cffi==1.11.5
chardet==3.0.4
Click==7.0
croniter==0.3.25
cryptography==2.3.1
dill==0.2.8.2
docutils==0.14
enum34==1.1.6
filechunkio==1.8
Flask==0.11.1
Flask-Admin==1.4.1
Flask-Cache==0.13.1
Flask-Login==0.2.11
flask-swagger==0.2.13
Flask-WTF==0.12
funcsigs==1.0.0
future==0.15.2
futures==3.2.0
gitdb2==2.0.5
GitPython==2.1.11
google-api-core==1.5.1
google-api-python-client==1.5.5
google-auth==1.5.1
google-auth-httplib2==0.0.3
google-auth-oauthlib==0.2.0
google-cloud-bigquery==1.6.0
google-cloud-core==0.28.1
google-resumable-media==0.3.1
googleapis-common-protos==1.5.3
gunicorn==19.3.0
httplib2==0.11.3
idna==2.7
ipaddress==1.0.22
itsdangerous==1.1.0
JayDeBeApi==1.1.1
Jinja2==2.8.1
JPype1==0.6.3
lockfile==0.12.2
lxml==3.8.0
Mako==1.0.7
Markdown==2.6.11
MarkupSafe==1.0
MySQL-python==1.2.5
numpy==1.15.3
oauth2client==2.0.2
oauthlib==2.1.0
ordereddict==1.1
pandas==0.18.1
pandas-gbq==0.7.0
protobuf==3.6.1
psutil==4.4.2
psycopg2==2.7.5
pyasn1==0.4.4
pyasn1-modules==0.2.2
pycparser==2.19
Pygments==2.2.0
pyOpenSSL==18.0.0
python-daemon==2.1.2
python-dateutil==2.7.5
python-editor==1.0.3
python-nvd3==0.14.2
python-slugify==1.1.4
pytz==2018.7
PyYAML==3.13
requests==2.20.0
requests-oauthlib==1.0.0
rsa==4.0
setproctitle==1.1.10
six==1.11.0
smmap2==2.0.5
SQLAlchemy==1.2.12
tabulate==0.7.7
thrift==0.9.3
Unidecode==1.0.22
uritemplate==3.0.0
urllib3==1.24
Werkzeug==0.14.1
WTForms==2.2.1
zope.deprecation==4.3.0
```

Comment: If you test with a previous version of `gcloud bq` does it work? Which docker image are you using?

Comment: I'm using https://hub.docker.com/r/continuumio/miniconda2/ image, and I don't have `gcloud bq`

Comment: Interesting, I just started a new container from the same image as yours, installed gcloud and it's working just fine...I wonder what is your output of `pip freeze`?

Comment: I've added it @WillianFuks. Is this the `/opt/conda/envs/env/bin/pip` that you're using to install gcloud?   `export PATH=/opt/conda/envs/env/bin:$PATH`. Thank you

Comment: I've installed gcloud by downloading it from here: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/quickstart-linux. I asked about the pip freeze just to see if you have something different from mine environment that might be affecting python.

Comment: sorry, yes, the pip freeze output is pasted into the original question now. Ah ok, i should try install not with apt-get, but as per the link u pasted above

Comment: Have you logged in with the `gcloud init` first? @Joice

Comment: yes, I did. Your environment is pretty much the same as mine...don't know what's causing this conflict them...

Comment: Yes, I've done `gcloud init`, the configuration looks good, I also did everything from scratch w/ a new container and it's still not working.  I'll try another container I guess.

Comment: ok, this container works https://hub.docker.com/r/google/cloud-sdk/

Comment: No answer to this question?